# Using XSLT format-number function to round value to 2 decimal place monatery amount

Tags: xml, xslt, format, decimal, biztalk

I need to format a monetary amount to 2 decimal places, even though there are actually 4 decimals in the amount. The last 2 decimals should always be 0.

As an example:

2480**130** should be formatted to 2480**100**

The length of the value should remain the same, but the last 2 digits should always be zero to round down the monetary value.

Currently I am using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number((Amounts/NetUnitPrice * 10000),'############00')"/>
```

But this does not transform the last 2 digits to be 0.

Some documentation on the format-number function can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_formatnumber.asp

What pattern can I use to accomplish this using the format-number function? It's very important that the monetary value not be changed in any way, other than to be rounded down to 2 decimal places. Is there another function that I should use for this instead?

Comment: What is the actual input here? Rounding 2480130 to 2480100 is trivial: `round($number div 100) * 100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, by shortening the amount by 2 decimals and concatenating "00" at the end of the value. This also correctly rounds the value up/down. See the code below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number((Amounts/NetUnitPrice * 100),'#############0'), '00')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this. It will replace the last 2 digits to 00.

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(format-number((Amounts/NetUnitPrice* 10000),'############00'), '..$', '00')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I can only use XSLT 1.0, so the replace function isn't available to me. Is there a similar function available for XSL 1.0 that I can use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Note that format-number() in XSLT 1.0 doesn't clearly specify what rounding algorithm is used. It's sort-of defined by reference to the JDK 1.1 specification (which is rather difficult to get your hands on nowadays), but Java offers a choice of rounding algorithms and XSLT 1.0 doesn't say which is used. So it's best not to rely on `format-number()` to round towards zero, even if that's what your current implementation does.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, I am aware format-number does use some unclearly defined rounding algorithm. In this case though it works well enough for the requirement.